# How to fetch one million documents from firebase firestore database without query interruption?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am writing a mobile app in React Native and I need to fetch a million documents from Firestore Firebase.

By sending a simple `.get()` the query takes too long and gets aborted.

Using `await` and pagination (`orderBy`, `startAfter` and `limit`) the download works but takes a very long time. I download the entire collection in chunks of 10,000 documents.

Is there any faster way to download a large number of documents from Firestore Firebase? Is it possible to do this without using `orderBy`?

Comment: "I need to fetch a million documents from firestore" Trying to do that in a mobile app, sounds like a recipe for problems. "Why is retrieving a million document slow" sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What use-case requires that you load that many documents into **a mobile app** to being with? There are probably better ways to implement such a use-case.

Comment: It's not standard to fetch all 1M documents at once. Can you add more details why you want to do this?

Comment: Need to read this data in offline mode.

Comment: So are you willing to load those documents in smaller batches?

Comment: Fetching these documents in smaller chunks is necessary so that the query does not get interrupted.

Comment: Have you considered checking Firebase Realtime Database? For starters, you can check this [post](https://firebase.blog/posts/2017/10/cloud-firestore-for-rtdb-developers) and also check the [Realtime Database Limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits).